# Subquery the same table : Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have got a scenario where I would want the below query executed using sequelize.

> select * from master where catg_level = 1 and obj_id in (select obj_id from master where catg_level = 2) order by position;

I've the below code written in sequelize.

```
Master.all({
  where: {catg_level: '1'}, 
  order: 'position ASC', 
  include: [{
    model: Master, 
    as: 'sub-menu', 
    where: {catg_level: '2'}
  }]
})
.then(function(a){
  try {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

The SQL generated this

[image]

The condition catg_level = 2 is added to the main query instead of being added as a subquery. I understand this is the actual functioning. But is there a workaround to get this done? Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sequelize.literal`:

```
{
    where: {
        catg_level: '1',
        obj_id:{
            in:[sequelize.literal('(select obj_id from master where catg_level = 2)')]
        }
    },
    order: 'position ASC',
}
```

Comment: I would preferably not want to use direct querying for performance reasons. Is there any workaround for this?